# Not able to call WebAPI from JQuery client

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-web-api

i try to figure out how to call my webAPI from Jquery. i tried a lot of tricks, but that doesn't work.

i have to use jsonp cause i'm doing cross-domain.

this is my code :

```
window.myCallback = function(data) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(data));
};

$.ajax({
  url: "http://keolisdriverswebapi-test.azurewebsites.net/api/jsonp/",
  type: 'GET',
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  jsonp: 'callback',
  jsonpCallback: 'myCallback'
});
```

there is no error while running this code, i receive a code 200 while profiling, but the callback is not called.

How can i call my url and handle the result.

you can have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/KeolisCanada/D4S9x/

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You're expecting JSONP, but the page you're trying to get only contains

```
{"foo":"bar"}
```

and that's not JSONP, it's just regular JSON. If it where JSONP it would be wrapped in the callback function, like so

```
myCallback({"foo":"bar"});
```